# Mechanize open javascript link python

Tags: javascript, python, mechanize

How to open javascript link in mechanize:

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="showTradingData('SelectContract');">Place Order</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mechanize cannot handle javascript-logic based links.

One option would be to inspect to which URL a request is being made while clicking on the link in the browser using browser developer tools. Then, simulate it using `mechanize`.

Another option would be to switch to browser-based tools like [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).